# Proper way to store image in elasticsearch with python 3.6.0

Tags: image, python-3.x, elasticsearch

Constrains

- Language Python 3.6.0
- Image size up to 5MB [formats .PNG .JPG and .JEPG]
- I have to store image in elasticsearch. It's a requirement. However which format I use is not important as long as image can be reconstructed.

I have the physical location of the image. I opened the image and converted it to `base64` format. Then I am trying to index it in elasticsearch running on my `localhost`. But it is not working. I assume I need to use the bulk api here. But I found out bulk api takes `actions` or `generators`. In my case how can I use bulk to save my image in elasticsearch? Or is there any other efecient way to index images in elasticsearch?

Please note that, I can successfully load and encode image into `bytes`. Also other `Index` and `Search(GET)` queries are working fine on my `localhost:9200`.

Here is my approach so far.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import uuid
import base64

client = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port':9200}])
def persist_image_in_elastic(imagePath):
     curMethodst = time.time()
     # imagePath = 'images/heroalom/image_22.png'
     with open(imagePath, "rb") as imageFile:
          rawImage = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())

     elasticIndex = 'raw-image-index'
     doc_type = 'raw-image'
     rawImageModel = {'id': 'f00b5f7c17534d22ab5cfb950bea972c', 'raw': rawImage }
     elasticResp = client.index(index = elasticIndex, doc_type = doc_type,id = idForReceivedImage, body = rawImageModel)
```

Mapping of elasticsearch

```
{
   "raw-image-index": {
      "mappings": {
         "raw-image": {
            "properties": {
               "id": {
                  "type": "text"
               },
               "raw": {
                  "type": "text"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Only thing you need to do is to wrap `rawImage` in `str()` call, like this:

```
rawImageModel = {'id': 'f00b5f7c17534d22ab5cfb950bea972c', 'raw': str(rawImage) }
```

Now a bit of explanation. [base64.b64encode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode) returns you an object of type [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes), while ElasticSearch client expects `string`.

In fact, the python code you provided throws an exception you could use to debug:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 19, in <module>
    persist_image_in_elastic('/Users/vasiliev/Downloads/es_logo_small.png')
  File "code.py", line 17, in persist_image_in_elastic
    elasticResp = client.index(index = elasticIndex, doc_type = doc_type,id = 'f00b5f7c17534d22ab5cfb950bea972c', body = rawImageModel)
  File "/Users/vasiliev/.virtualenvs/es-blob-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 73, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/vasiliev/.virtualenvs/es-blob-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 298, in index
    _make_path(index, doc_type, id), params=params, body=body)
  File "/Users/vasiliev/.virtualenvs/es-blob-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 278, in perform_request
    body = self.serializer.dumps(body)
  File "/Users/vasiliev/.virtualenvs/es-blob-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/serializer.py", line 50, in dumps
    raise SerializationError(data, e)
elasticsearch.exceptions.SerializationError: ({'id': 'f00b5f7c17534d22ab5cfb950bea972c', 'raw': b'iVB...mCC'}, TypeError("Unable to serialize b'iVB...mCC' (type: <class 'bytes'>)",))
```

As final remark please consider using [Binary data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/binary.html) for storing binary data. With the mapping you provided ElasticSearch will store all your binary objects in the full-text search index, which you won't be querying. Another option is to set this field as not-indexed:

```
{
   "raw-image-index": {
      "mappings": {
         "raw-image": {
            "properties": {
               "id": {
                  "type": "text"
               },
               "raw": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "index": "no"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: on a different note, which IDE you are using? (Just asking)

Comment: To work with this code I used just vim. For larger python apps/scripts I use PyCharm, it has Community Edition (free) and fits my needs.